# Attempting to set items in a spinner, but no items in the list display on click

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to set the items in a spinner within a fragment to have a list from the strings file. However, when I test the app, no items populate the spinner in the fragment. No errors are given.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class CompareFragment extends Fragment {


    public CompareFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_compare, container, false);
        setSpinnerContent(view);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_compare, container, false);
    }
    private void setSpinnerContent( View view )
    {
        Spinner spinnerL = (Spinner) view.findViewById( R.id.spinnerL );
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getContext(),
                R.array.the_list, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerL.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

How may I populate the spinner in the fragment? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use return view;

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_compare, container, false);
        setSpinnerContent(view);
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: Adding `return view;` seemed to fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this 
change this

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getContext(),
                R.array.the_list, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

to

```
 ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getContext(),
                     android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,R.array.the_list);
```

Refer here for more: http://coderzpassion.com/android-working-with-spinner/

Also change OnCreateView last line to

```
return view;
```